# Shell script problem to set my env

Tags: shell, environment-variables, unix

We have few executable which need some environment setting.
We manually running those scripts before running the executable

Like

```
$ . setenv.ksh
```

We have to encompass call these in one script to avoid the manual work.
We written a sh script like

```
#!/bin/sh

. setenv.ksh

./abc &
```

Still the environments are not setting in that session. I think the “. setenv.ksh” runs with fork and it’s not setting the environment.

Please me to solve this problem. Which command we use to run the setenv.ksh so, this will work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the contents of `setenv.ksh`, or at least a portion of it that shows the problem? And try to demonstrate the problem, e.g. replace `./abc` by `env | grep foo` where `foo` is a variable that should be set by `setenv.ksh` but is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the environment script is called `setenv.ksh` but you try to run it from `/bin/sh`. Maybe your system has a shell other than ksh as `/bin/sh` and it misparses something it `setenv.ksh`. Try changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/ksh` (or whatever the path to ksh is on your system).

Answer (score 1):

In setenv.ksh, you need to export all environment variables you set so that any sub-shell will inherit the values:

```
export MYENV=myValue
```

Comment: Setenv.ksh is the third party file. We can not edit it otherwise face problem on the installed system.